# Android Emulator screen mirror and control in browser?

Tags: android, emulation

There are some online Android emulators on the web where you can start an emulator install apps and control your virtual device in the browser.
I want to develop the same thing in my local network where 1 server is deploying the virtual devices. A local web page where my collegues can start devices form the list and install apks for testing.
I can not find any start point and research point.
Can you tell me where to start? All google searches delivers me only adds and commercial online emulator websites. How did they do it? how to output the screen in browser and how to control?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cool solution.
The magic is phpVirtualBox.
[Can be foudn here](https://github.com/phpvirtualbox/phpvirtualbox)